# Регулярные выражения слэш

Tags: php

Как в коде

```
$query = preg_replace('![^\w\d\-\]*!', '', $query);
```

задать символ '/' так, чтобы его тоже расспознавало и считывало? К примеру, мне нужно чтоб значение $query ='WT/KSK.80/1' сохраняло свои слеши после обработки, сейчас они исчезают

Comment: я конечно могу ошибаться, но кажись у вас лишний обратный слеш.
`$query = preg_replace('![^\/\w\d\-]*!', '', $query);`

Comment: какой результат вы хотите получить?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
$query = preg_replace('![^\/\w\d\-\]*!', '', $query);
```

Comment: немного не то. К примеру, мне нужно чтоб значение $query ='WT/KSK.80/1' сохраняло свои слеши после обработки, сейчас они исчезают

Comment: Ну так, preg_replace заменяет все символы в регулярке, на пустой пробел.
Используйте тогда preg_match.